# extend the Mytiny todo module in drupal7

Tags: php, view, hook, block, alter

I am trying to extend the *Mytiny* todo module. Basically, I want to add two more fields like Repeat and url fields with validation. But when I am trying to it with `hook_block_view_alter()`, the fields are showing outside the block, whereas I want to show it on the task form field. I am trying to this for adding fields:

```
<?php
function todo_block_view_alter(&$data, $block)
{
dsm($block);
if (is_array($data['content']) && $block->module == 'system') {
$data = array();
$data['content'] ['name'] = array(
'#type' => 'textfield',
'#title' => 'Your Name',
'#size' => 60,
'#required' => TRUE,

);
}
}
```

If anybody has the answer than please give me the solution as soon as you can.

Thanking You in advance.